# Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex is case insensitive

Tags: zend-framework, routes, case-insensitive

For those wondering why `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex` matches case-different routes, eg. hxxp://example.com/EN vs. hxxp://example.com/en, here's an explanation.

`Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex` is implicitly case insensitive. It is set in `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex::match()` method. This is the piece of code that sets `PCRE_CASELESS` modifier:

```
if (!$partial) {
 $path = trim(urldecode($path), '/');
 $regex = '#^' . $this->_regex . '$#i';
} else {
 $regex = '#^' . $this->_regex . '#i';
}
```

I do not know if there is any way to suppress this behavior from inside of the regular expression. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex` and just write a different `match` method, where the only difference would be in the regex pattern minus the `i` flag.